# efficient way to count adjacent empty points of a connected group on a grid

Tags: c, algorithm, x86, simd, avx

A connected group means a set of vertices of equal values on a grid being adjacent horizontally or vertically.

For example, on this grid where `.` is an empty point, there are 4 connected groups.

```
X O O .      X       O O
. X O X  ->       X    O  X
X X O X         X X    O  X
```

You can also see that each group has 1 *connected* empty point.

I'm trying to count the number of these connected empty points given a grid and the coordinates that point to a vertex of a group.

If the input is,

```
. . X X X O O . 
X X . X . X O X 
. X X X X X O X 
X X . O O X . X 

(0, 2)
```

The output should be `7` because the big group including the vertex at `(0, 2)` (row, column) has `7` connected empty points.

If you are familiar of the game of Go (baduk), connected empty point is in other words *liberty*. This operation is the core of a routine analyzing a position in Go, and it has to be done fast.

Below is my try. It's terribly inefficient in many ways involving a lot of branches and recursion. I'm tracking the 4 possible directions and incrementing the count whenever there's an empty space, and put a mark on the vertex at which the counting has been done to not count twice.

Could you shed some light on how to efficiently solve this problem?

General algorithmic improvement and x86-AVX2-specific optimizations are both welcome.

```
typedef __attribute__((vector_size(32))) char vec8_c;

enum {H = 4, W = 8};

static int count_();
static int count__();

static int count(vec8_c x, int i, int j) {
    vec8_c m = {0};
    return count_((char *)&x, (char *)&m, i, j, i * W + j);
}

static int count_(char *x, char *m, int i, int j, int idx) {
    m[idx] = 1;
    int r = 0;
    if (j - 1 >= 0) {
        r += count__(x, m, i, j - 1, idx - 1, idx);
    }
    if (j + 1 < W) {
        r += count__(x, m, i, j + 1, idx + 1, idx);
    }
    if (i - 1 >= 0) {
        r += count__(x, m, i - 1, j, idx - W, idx);
    }
    if (i + 1 < H) {
        r += count__(x, m, i + 1, j, idx + W, idx);
    }
    return r;
}

static int count__(char *x, char *m, int i, int j, int idx, int idx_) {
    if (!m[idx]) {
        if (!x[idx]) {
            m[idx] = 1;
            return 1;
        } else if (x[idx] == x[idx_]) {
            return count_(x, m, i, j, idx);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Run online](https://godbolt.org/z/boj8Txb13).

Comment: Probably belongs on codereview, not stack overflow. Some minor points to help... Use a queue instead of recursion. The queue can be held as a plain array and you maintain a head and tail pointer or index. Avoid the use of 2D indices. Multiplication is a cost. You can store the position as just a pointer or a 1D index, and use offsets from there (-W, -1, 1, W). Consider some branchless code for both counting and queuing, then measure it. _e.g._ `int *n = p-W; count += (*n==0); *tail = n; tail += (*n==*p);` -- where `p` points to the current stone having its neighbours tested.

Comment: @paddy I'm not asking for a review of my code. I'm just showing what I tried to solve this problem. The question holds without my code.

Comment: You asked how to make it more efficient. I offered some suggestions.

Comment: @paddy I replied to your first sentence. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: My first sentence is in regards to the purpose of Stack Overflow versus the purpose of Code Review. This website leans toward code that doesn't work correctly, whereas Code Review leans toward seeking feedback/improvements.

Comment: I'll also mention that in Go, analyzing a position is generally an update step. Most moves require the addition of a single stone to the board, meaning that a global analysis is pointless if you already have a current analysis of the board state including all groups and liberties. Read up on graph theory, connected components, etc.

Comment: @paddy I find many "related" questions asking for efficient algorithms for a certain problem, so I don't think my question is far from the purpose of Stackoverflow. For the "current analysis" you mentioned, the number of liberties has to be counted somehow. Yes, probably interpreting the board as a graph is a valid approach. Thank you.

Comment: @paddy: questions asking for new code, especially a SIMD-optimized version of a scalar problem, belong on Stack Overflow, definitely not codereview.  Such questions should have working scalar code as an example of what's wanted, as well as English description that makes it clear which behaviours of the scalar code are necessary and which are implementation details.  (i.e. what assumptions a SIMD implementation could make.)  This question doesn't want comments on the coding-style, efficiency, or other quality of its scalar example; the OP knows it has big problems, so it's not a code review.

Comment: Counting neighbour states around a single point is a simpler problem, as in Conway's game of life (finite automata): https://github.com/lemire/SIMDgameoflife / https://lemire.me/blog/2018/07/18/accelerating-conways-game-of-life-with-simd-instructions/  But obviously the hard part is extending that to connected areas; I don't think that's a promising starting point, just what I first thought of before fully taking in the title question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I realized before this question that counting the empty points around a single point can be done by convolution with `[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0]`. There must be an efficient parallel way to do this since this is a common operation for graphic cards.

Comment: @PeterCordes For the current problem, I think I found a reasonable approach (by someone else). It involves matrix transposition, and just because of this, I'm thinking of using AVX-512. See, you can get a transpose of a large matrix by computing the transpose of smaller square parts and combining. For this square matrix transposition, if each element is a byte, *an 8x8 transpose can be computed by a single shuffle in a `zmm`*. One worry is that it seems Intel has basically discontinued AVX-512.

Comment: IDK what Intel's planning for AVX-512 in "client" CPUs, but it's going strong in servers.  There haven't been any Xeons without between Skylake-server and now.  (IDK if they're planning any siblings to Sapphire Rapids that have some E-cores like Alder Lake, though, without AVX-512.)

Answer (score 2):

From the description I would convert the problem into intersection/union;

- Make a mask C from the connected component
- Make a mask E from the empty pixels
- Make a larger mask M by concatenating the shifted version of C
  `M = C<<1 | C^^1 | C >> 1 | C^^-1`
- return PopCount(M & E)

This approach should easily vectorize and even autovectorize.

When C is large enough, use SIMD registers to work in blocks of 16x8, where each bit represents a boolean in the mask. One can then shift a whole block up/down by `alignr` / left/right with `_mm_slli_epi16/_mm_srli_epi16` or their equivalents in AVX2/-512, where unfortunately the cross bank shifting is a bit costly.

For the specific inputs:

```
. . X X X O O . -> C = 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  E = 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
X X . X . X O X        1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0      0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
. X X X X X O X        0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
X X . O O X . X        1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0      0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Then the mask M would be the union of C shifted to left,right,up,down

```
M =   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
      0 |1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0| 0  <-- you only need the
      1 |1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0| 0      inner / 'valid' area
      0 |1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0| 0
      1 |1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0| 0
      0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0

M.*E =    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
          0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
          1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
          0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0,  sum == 7
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what `C` is? I'm currently investigating a solution that produces 2 adjacency matrices and combines them somehow with boolean operators ([link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247451/108859)). It feels like your approach is related to this. I don't have a strong mathematics base, so a kinder explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Mask is a 2-dimensional boolean array with a bit set if the element belongs to the set 'C = Connected' or to the set 'E', which stands for 'Empty pixels' or 'Edge'.
The mask is likely best to be packed, i.e. not spending 8 or 32 bits to represent just one bit.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the examples. Then the problem would be what is an efficient way to compute `C`.

Comment: The other question is what are the possible dimensions of C. In Go it's likely 19x19 or what?

Comment: For the current purpose (evaluating local life/death status), I'm sticking to 4x8 for easier optimization.

Comment: 8x4 or 4x8 would fit uint32_t; And then the next obvious choice would be `uint64_t` to store 8x8 or 4x16 block.

Comment: I think the hard part of the OP’s question is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling Technically possible to do efficiently with SIMD, I did before, however the implementation is very hard. Gonna be way more code than what’s reasonable to write in an answer. The flood fill algorithm which detects and erases a connected component of the bitmap needs the ability to “leak” across blocks.

Comment: @Soonts: I read anyway from the question, that the labelling is already given. If it's not, I would not go for a parallel/simdified union-find, that's overkill. The equivalence map will likely have a depth of 2 max with path compression.